# How to convert a string date in mongodb to ISODate(), or DATE() and delete if it is less than 30 days using python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Using python I saved dates into MongoDB in below format,

```
completed_time : "2017:08:20 02:30:02"
```

Now I want to delete all entries which are older than 30 days.
How can I implement that logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it more simply. This code is considerably longer than needed, in order to be explanatory.

I first create a collection of MongoDB records with dates that start from about a month and a half ago, and end about two two weeks ago.

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> client = MongoClient()
>>> db = client.test_database
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> some_dates = [datetime(2017, 7, d).strftime('%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S') for d in range(15,31)]+[datetime(2017, 8, d).strftime('%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S') for d in range(1,16)]
>>> posts = db.create_collection
>>> for some_date in some_dates:
...     post = {'completed_time': some_date, 'stuff': 'more stuff'}
...     post_id = posts.insert_one(post).inserted_id
...
```

This calculates the time and date that is (or was) 30 days earlier than 'now' when I calculated it, and puts it in the format in you MongoDB database.

```
>>> boundary = (datetime.now()-timedelta(30)).strftime('%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S')
```

This counts the number of records in the database whose dates and times precede the value in `boundary` just calculated, for later reference.

```
>>> count = 0
>>> for post in posts.find({'completed_time': {'$lt': boundary}}):
...     count+=1
... 
>>> count
19
```

This is the **one** line that, with the calculation of `boundary`, does what you want.

```
>>> r = posts.delete_many({'completed_time': {'$lt': boundary}})
```

Now we can check that the correct number of records has been deleted.

```
>>> count = 0
>>> for post in posts.find({'completed_time': {'$lt': boundary}}):
...     count+=1
... 
>>> count
0
```

Comment: I have one doubt: {'$lt': boundary}  => does this calculate date is less than or the sum of number in "boundary" is less than? If the latter is the case, is there any chance to fail in future?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. I'll try answering in this way and if it's not what you want to know please try again. The calculation for `boundary` calculates just one time, relative to `now`. In this example `posts` contains *all* of the postings in the database. However, `{'completed_time': {'$lt': boundary}}` considers postings *one at a time*. I mean, each `completed_time` is either less than (ie, 'before') `boundary` or it's not. If any given posting is less than `boundary` then it will be deleted. Maybe you're thinking of the fact that `now` is not fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `datetime` module to convert your date/time string into a `datetime` object, and then convert it to an ordinal day (just a single number), and compare it to the day that was thirty days ago.

Hopefully this will do what you want:

```
import datetime

completed_time = "2017:07:20 02:30:02"

timeFormat = '%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S'
thisDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(completed_time, timeFormat).toordinal()

today = datetime.date.today()
thirtyDaysAgo = today.toordinal() - 30

if thisDate < thirtyDaysAgo:
    print("That needs deleting!")
```